# Where to reference JavaScript files for Ionic's template/[xxx].html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to reference JavaScript files for my Ionic Mobile Apps project's navigation.html, located inside the www/templates/ directory.

*Note : I created the project using the side menu template in Visual Studio 2015 and the project includes an index.html, and all those html pages located inside the www/templates/ directory are using the index.html, something like master page.

In my navigation.html, I have the following code snippet:

```
   <ion-view view-title="Navigation">
    <ion-content>
        // my html codes will be stored here
     </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
```

I tried to reference the JavaScript files in the index.html but I received some error. So I wanna reference the JavaScript files inside the navigation.html. However, since my navigation.html does not have tags, like , , I created them inside the navigation.html. After modifying the navigation.html and putting the reference for the JavaScript files in the navigation.html, it looked like this.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  // some js files 
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
```

However, the javascript files are not loaded in the navigation.html. It is supposed to work as I have tried in notepad++, the same codes, and it worked perfectly. I have tried a couple different things, but cannot get the javascript files loaded in the navigation.html. Does anyone know a way I could make this work? Thanks.

Comment: "I tried to reference the JavaScript files in the index.html but I received some error." What errors have you got?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load files (and plug in) only for some views instead of all your app you can use oclazy (https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad)
And use like this in your routing:

$stateProvider

```
    .state("index", {
        preload: true,
        abstract: true, //<-- THIS IS A FATHER VIEW
        url: "/index",
        templateUrl: "/app/view/template/common/content.html"
    })
    .state("index.main", {
        url: "/main",
        templateUrl: "/app/view/template/home/home_new.html",
        data: { pageTitle: "Home" },
        controller: "HomeController",
        controllerAs: "homeCtrl",
        resolve: {
            loadPlugin: function ($ocLazyLoad) { //<-- HERE YOU CAN LOAD FILES ONLY FOR YOUR ROUTING
                return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                    {
                        name: "ngTagsInput",
                        files: ["/app/view/assets/lib/bower/ng-tags-input/ng-tags-input.js"]
                    },
                ]);
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: I have many plugins and JS files to be loaded for the navigation.html. As I have mentioned above that the javascript files and plugins are not loaded or cannot be called in the navigation.html. Why is it not working? Is it because of dependency? Can you explain to me please?